# Forcing Wordpress Header to not refresh on page load

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, mp3

I developed a band website using wordpress, and I placed a flash MP3 player that autoplays in the header. Whenever you click on a link, the entire page refreshes and the mp3 player starts playing the first song all over again. I wish to have the entire header including the mp3 player) stay constant while the content/sidebar/footer reloads when you click a link. That way the music will continue playing while the rest of the page loads, and the user can have a real listening experience.

To all of your knowledge, is there any way to do this without making the rest of the site completely dynamic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: nope. i dont think so. you need ajax the site completely.

Comment: I see that there are some plugins like this one that ajaxify a wp site: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxd-wordpress/

Comment: although they don't work like I want them too. I really don't want to ajax the entire site. I just want one 300px x 200px block that holds the player that Always plays and is not affected by a page change. Never seen that before though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are acutally only two ways to do this without Ajax:

1. Use a frameset (which is a very bad idea nowadays)
2. Use a pop-up which holds the player

I know that pop-ups might be blocked, but this is the only way that users will accept. many large sites with audio players use pop-ups for such a functionality.

Comment: Would a frameset work here? Even when I click a nav link, wouldn't the entire page reload, including the frame?

Comment: If you create a frameset "arround" WordPress (so WordPress runs in the main frame) only this frame will be reloaded each time a users clicks a link within WordPress.

But usings framesets will completely destroy bookmarking so it is not the best solution!!